# provided in react-beautiful-dnd library

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm doing "To do List", and I want to move the columns as well as the cards, and I want to do drag and drop.

My problem is that I can't understand these terms:

1. "provided".
2. "provided.draggableProps"

3."provided.dragHandleProps"

4."provided.innerRef".

```
  <Draggable draggableId={props.task.id} index={props.index}>
        {(provided) => (
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              flexWrap: "wrap",
              "& > :not(style)": {
                m: 1,
                width: 128,
                height: 128,
              },
            }}
            // i put it in the component that i want to move it
            {...provided.draggableProps}
            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
            ref={provided.innerRef}
          >
            <Paper elevation={3}>{props.task.content}</Paper>
          </Box>
        )}
      </Draggable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a function immediately inside of that **Draggable** component that passes in the **provided** argument.

**Note:** This function can pass in two arguments including a snapshot argument, but I guess you are not using it.

The **provided** argument include information and references to code that the library needs to work properly.

You added **provided.innerRef** which is going to create a reference for the library to access the list element’s HTML element.  It also applies props to the element **(provided.draggableProps)** that allows the library to keep track of movements and positioning.

**provided.draggableProps** - This is an Object that contains a data attribute and an inline style. This Object needs to be applied to the same node that you apply **provided.innerRef** to. This controls the movement of the draggable when it is dragging and not dragging

**provided.dragHandleProps** - (?DragHandleProps) every **Draggable** has a drag handle. This is what is used to drag the whole **Draggable**. Often this will be the same node as the , but sometimes it can be a child of the **Draggable**. DragHandleProps need to be applied to the node that you want to be the drag handle. This is a number of props that need to be applied to the **Draggable** node.

If you need more information feel free to read from the documentation

```
https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd
```